# Stick div to top of page when start scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to make a div (id="hoe") that sticks to the top of the from the moment the user scrolls. before scrolling, the div is located under the header. Unfortunately, i can't get it to work after lot's of trying. Any tips and help on what I do wrong is greatly appreciated. Here is my code in a test version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<style type="text/css">

#header
{
background-color: blue;
width: 100%;
height: 125px;
}

#hoe
{ 
background-color: red;
height: 180px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
top: 125;
position: fixed;
}

#een
{
margin-top: 180px;
background-color: green;
height: 700px;
width: 100%;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($('body').hasClass('lock')) {
    bar_pos = $('#hoe').offset();
    if (bar_pos.top >= (125+180)) {
        $('#hoe').css('top', 0);
        //document.getElementById("hoe").style.top="0"; also tried this
    }
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body class="lock">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="hoe">
</div>
<div id="een">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First thing to do is to learn HTML : 
`<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>` - http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/hEH3b/ looks like it's working or I don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: jsfiddle would be appricated; however you can use existing plugin like http://stickyjs.com/ instead of writing your own :)

Comment: Use this lightweight (~4KB) plugin: http://simianstudios.com/portamento

Comment: There no need for any plugin check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627636/how-to-make-a-div-scroll-up-and-fix-at-the-top/11628528#11628528

Comment: @soyuka: Oops, was merely a typo when i was copying code. Thanks for the jdfiddle tip, didn't know it yet, will be using it from now on. The problem is that from the moment that you start scrolling, the red div should stick to the top of the page. Tested the jsfiddle with different browsers too, but the red div just stays at it's place (125px from the top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code and created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UcX4A/

There was a surplus bracket in your javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('lock')) {
        bar_pos = $('#hoe').offset();
        if (bar_pos.top >= (125+180)) {
            $('#hoe').css('top', 0);
            //document.getElementById("hoe").style.top="0"; also tried this
        }
    }); <<< Surplus bracket
});
```

Also, the "scroll" event wasn't attached to anything, so wasn't being evaluated.  I changed your:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

To a:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. Now I can expand this function and learn new things.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working now. The top, blue area disappears forever once you scroll down. Is that the intended effect? I thought it was to have the second div stick to the top as long as you are scrolled below it, but then move back down as you scroll up to the top.

Answer (score 1):

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/WTnEd/

Use [$(window).scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var bar_pos;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    if ($('body').hasClass('lock')) {
        bar_pos = $('#hoe').offset();
        if (bar_pos.top >= (125 + 180)) {
            $('#hoe').css('top', 0);
        }
        else{
            $('#hoe').css('top', 125);
        }
    };
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, this is an alternate way to stick div to top of page when start scrolling:

```
<div id="header" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;
    height:100px; z-index:2; background:blue;"></div>
<div id="hoe" style="position:fixed; top:100px; left:0px; right:0px;
    height:100px; z-index:2; background:red;"></div>
<div id="een" style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:0px; right:0px;
    height:100px; z-index:1;">
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
  <p>dummy text</p>
</div>
```